# Backbone.js Model to View Connection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am a Backbone.js newbie. I was just playing around with it. I would like to know whether the model is related with the View. In the provided [todos](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html) example, I see in the addOne method, a new View is created and associated with the newly created model and appended.

```
  window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
     // view code
     addOne: function(todo) {
          var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
          this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
     }
  }
```

When I tried to do a similar thing, I got an error saying "bind method cannot be found on undefined".

```
window.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

     initialize: function() {
          _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'close');
          this.model.bind('change', this.render); // I got the error at this place. 
          this.model.view = this;
     }
});
```

In order to solve this, I got to pass the newly created model as a param to the view constructor and I got to do `this.model = task` inorder to associate it.

```
window.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

     initialize: function(task) {
          _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'close');
          this.model = task
          this.model.bind('change', this.render);// now there is no error
          this.model.view = this;
     }
});

window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({


   insertTask:function(){
        var newTask, newTaskView;
        newTask = new Task(JSON.parse(xhr));
        Tasks.create(newTask);
        newTaskView = new TaskView({ model: newTask });
        $("#todo_list").append(newTaskView.render().el);
        this.input.val('');
}
```

});

But the todos example, do not have something like that. How is the new model associated with the new view implicitly in the todos example?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you have `Task` constructor?

Comment: In your call to `this.model.bind` you need to pass the correct context. The model uses `this` in it's context so you need to tell it to render the view and not itself. `this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);`

Answer (score 38):

It's not implicit at all, it's explicit in this line right here:

```
var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
```

This is creating a new `TodoView` view and setting its `model` property to the `addOne` function's only parameter (`todo`, which is a model).

Whenever a new model is added to the `Todos` collection, the `addOne` method is called with the new model as the parameter.

```
Todos.bind('add', this.addOne);
```

Then, in `addOne`, a new view is created for that model and the relationship is explicity set, via `{model: todo}`. This is what you're missing from your version of the code, I suspect.

What you appear to be attempting to do is link up the view and the model in the view's init function, and that's fine, but you're on your own if you do that- which means you need to set up the model <-> view relationship yourself (which you have solved by passing the model as a parameter to the view init function).

Comment: When I tried to set like {model : todo }, I got an error that bind is not defined for change.basically what gets passed is a normal object without backbone model specific methods :(

Comment: Where do you set `{model: todo}`, you haven't shown that bit of your code. Are you confident that the `todo` variable isn't null in that context?

Comment: I have updated the question with the piece of code where the new taskview is created. no it was not null, it was an ordinary object.

Comment: I'm looking for the 'right' way to do this. Should the view decide which model it is attached to or should the model decice? Who's in charge of the view<->model connection in backbone?

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe there is no "right" way, cf http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-tim-toady "Backbone.js is intended to be fairly agnostic about many common patterns in client-side code" ... "References between Models and Views can be handled several ways"

Comment: @FactorMystic Yeah, I read that yesterday, too. In some cases, especially those closely related to framework functionality, I'd really like to see described one or several different good ways to accomplish something. http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns is a good start at that. Maybe I should contribute.